In category theory, are there any examples where the morphism of a product is not a epimorphism?
I tried some categories, and the morphisms $f_i$ of the product $(Z,f_i)$ are basically epimorphism. So I want to find some examples where the morphisms in the product are not epimorphism.
Product diagram

So I assume you tried the category of sets? There, it fails.
